# generating nil id having id sequence defined, Why?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, auto-increment, postgresql-11

I have a table named async_data, which has id column also auto increment defined. But in production I am seeing some insert queries are failing saying

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Rails Migration file

```
class CreateAsyncData < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :async_data do |t|
      t.integer :request_id
      t.integer :sourced_contact_id
      t.integer :data_source_id
      t.boolean :is_enriched
      t.column  :requested_params, :json
      t.text :q
      t.datetime :fetched_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
CREATE TABLE public.async_data (
        id integer NOT NULL,
        request_id integer,
        sourced_contact_id integer,
        data_source_id integer,
        is_enriched boolean DEFAULT false,
        requested_params json,
        fetched_at timestamp without time zone,
        created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        q text,
        is_processed boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
        is_data_pushed boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL
    );
```

\d async_data;

```
Table "public.async_data"
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                       
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('async_data_id_seq'::regclass)
 request_id        | integer                     |           |          | 
 source_company_id | integer                     |           |          | 
 data_source_id    | integer                     |           |          | 
 is_enriched       | boolean                     |           |          | 
 requested_params  | json                        |           |          | 
 q                 | text                        |           |          | 
 fetched_at        | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at        | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "async_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

```
--
-- Name: async_data_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE SEQUENCE public.async_data_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

I want to re-produce the same in dev environment and want to know why id nil was generated.

Comment: If the column has a default value, then apparently your code explicitly provided a NULL value during the INSERT

Comment: The default is 'NOT NULL', How it can generate NULL ?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE public.async_data (  id integer NOT NULL,`

Comment: The column `id` has defined sequence and it is auto incremented always and I am sure that I am not sending `id=NULL` explicitly. But somehow NULL was generated/assigned to `id` column, How ?

Are you sure the defined sequence never fails auto incrementing ?

Comment: Your code is most definitely sending a NULL value, otherwise you wouldn't get that error. And yes I am sure that the sequence never fails auto-incrementing. You are using a SQL statement that _prevents_ the usage of the sequence and the only case where that happens is, if you provide an explicit value.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, not sure why but the build was throwing an error on the sequence creation, looks like it shouldn't have "As integer"

I'm not sure if this has to do with the database client version or what, but just removing the "As integer" was the fix for me.